# Change all links inside an html file to add domain url

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-scraping, wget

I'm using wget to scrape a site and convert all the links to use downloaded resources.

I would like to know if there is any way to go through all links on a page, including stylesheets, scripts, links inside inline CSS, and add a domain to them.

all my links right now are like `/something.css` and I want to change them to `https://awebsite.com/something.csss`, wget doesn't seem to support this

ps: I need to change the links so I can serve the static site trough a proxy URL

Comment: Parse the file and the gsub each anchor node. Or remove all line endings, and prepend your preferred string.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using the base HTML tag to change bases

```
  <base href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
```

but that might not be a good solution for everyone, it worked on my case tho